# a C++ question about inheritance and reference

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

//base
class B
{
public：
    int dataB = 0;
};

//Derived
class D : public B
{
public:
    int dataD = 0;
};

class MyList
{
private:
    // store some B or D or other objects Derived from B
    // vector<B&> bList; // cant do this
    vector<B> bList;
public:
    void addB(B* newB, int newDataB)
    {
        // how to copy the data of newB, including dataB and dataD
        // push_back(I don't know if this is right)
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.dataD = 1;
    MyList myList;
    myList.addB(&d, 1); //dont want d to be changed
    myList.addB(&d, 2); //dont want d to be changed

    return 0; 
}
```

I want copy data from d to myList and change the dataB of the new element, but not change d, Idont know how to do that;

If I do this in addB:

```
  B* temp = new B(newB);
```

temp will only get dataB, dataD is discarded

And I **cant** do this in addB:

```
  D* temp = new D(newB);
```

Because there is not only D but also A or C or other class derived from B

Use dynamic_cast to access dataD in myList.

Comment: Which C++ book suggests that storing references in vectors is a good idea? (You can't do what you want to do by using references like this, C++ doesn't work like this)

Comment: Maybe a [factory method pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-patterns-set-2-factory-method/) would be useful to you here. Not 100% sure that's what you need though.

Comment: Your question is about making duplicates of objects the class of which is only known at runtime. Answer: There is nothing built into C++ for this, but you just have to create a common interface that all classes implement which return a copy of the actual object per class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* store `D`s in a `std::vector<B>`. You can only store a copy of the `B` portion of the `D`.

You *can* store a `D*` in a `std::vector<B*>`. Although if the vector is owning, it is better to use `std::unique_ptr<B>`

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

//base
class B
{
public：
    int dataB = 0;
};

//Derived
class D : public B
{
public:
    int dataD = 0;
};

class MyList
{
private:
    // store some B or D or other objects Derived from B
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> bList;
public:
    void addD(int dataB, int dataD)
    {
        bList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<D>(dataB, dataD));
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList myList;
    myList.addD(1, 1);
    myList.addD(2, 1);

    return 0; 
}
```

If you have lots of classes derived from `B`, you may want a template to add them to `MyList`.

```
template<typename Derived, typename... Args>
void MyList::addDerived(Args... args)
{
    bList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(args...));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the specific problem from your details. Still as i understood. This can work for you

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

// base
class B
{
public:
        int dataB = 0;
};

//Derived
class D : public B
{
public:
    int dataD = 0;
};

class MyList
{
private:
    // store some B or D or other objects Derived from B
    // vector<B&> bList; //cant do this
    vector<B> bList;
public:
    void addB(B* newB, int newDataB)
    {
        //how to copy the data of newB, including dataB and dataD
        //push_back(I don't know if this is right)
        (*newB).dataB = newDataB;
        bList.push_back(*newB);
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.dataD = 1;

    MyList myList;

    myList.addB(&d, 1);// dont want d to be changed
    myList.addB(&d, 2);// dont want d to be changed

    return 0;
}
```